# Finding the shortest path for every pair in a network

Tags: python, pandas, csv, networkx, graph-theory

I have a list of directed edges from parent to child in a csv file, as follows:

```
    parent  child
0   7       4847454
1   7       14823924
2   7       31208539
3   7       32584634
4   7       54293428
```

I want to find the shortest path between every possible pair of nodes in the network. How can I do that? I'm not sure which package is best in this case (networkX, igraph, etc)

Comment: Reinventing the wheel in this case is actually pretty simple, use `Floyd warshall` algorithm

Comment: @Raj Do you know of a library I can use this in?

Comment: As far as I know `networkX` would do that. I can't say which is best, it all depends on your application's needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using networkx, specifically [`nx.shortest_path`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path). This algorithm finds the shortest paths between a source & target node, or if none are specified, produces a dictionary of all shortest paths between every node pair (where a path exists).

For your example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'parent': {0: 7, 1: 7, 2: 7, 3: 7, 4: 7},
                   'child': {0: 4847454, 1: 14823924, 2: 31208539, 3: 32584634, 4: 54293428}})
>>> G = nx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'parent', 'child', create_using=nx.DiGraph)
>>> nx.shortest_path(G)
{7: {7: [7],
     4847454: [7, 4847454],
     14823924: [7, 14823924],
     31208539: [7, 31208539],
     32584634: [7, 32584634],
     54293428: [7, 54293428]},
 4847454: {4847454: [4847454]},
 14823924: {14823924: [14823924]},
 31208539: {31208539: [31208539]},
 32584634: {32584634: [32584634]},
 54293428: {54293428: [54293428]}}
```